# Jquery text not parsing into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code where I want a button's text to be stored in a variable and then set a text field's value to the text. Here's my code for the button onclick event:

```
$('#MyButton').click(function(){
        var user1 = $(this).attr("value");
        $('#MyTextField').val(user1);
    });
```

And Here is my button and text field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MyTextField" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to">
 <button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>
```

But nothing ever happens.
Please help,
Thanks in advance

EDIT regarding @Drakes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.18:8080');
$(window).load(function(){
    username = "<%= user.local.email %>";
    console.log(username);
    socket.emit('join', username);
    socket.on('userjoino', function(data){
        $('#users').empty();
        $('#puser').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $('#users').append('<div class="alert alert-warning">'+key+'</div>');
            $('#puser').append('<li class="list-group-item" id="whisper" rec="'+key+'"> <button id="whisper" class="btn btn-success MyButton" value="'+ key + '">'+ key + '</button></li>');
        });
        var users = data;
        console.log(users);
    });
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var message = $('#msg').val();
        if(message.length <= 0){
            $('#boxf').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">Message cannot be left empty</div>');
            var div = document.getElementById("boxf");
            div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
        }else{
        //var msgob = [nickname + ': ' + message];
        //socket.emit('message', msgob);
        socket.emit('message', message);
        $('#boxf').append('<div class="alert alert-info"> Me: ' + message + '</div>' );
        var div = document.getElementById("boxf");
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;

        $('#msg').val('');
        }
  });
    socket.on('messages', function(data){
        $("#boxf").append('<div class="alert alert-info" >' + data + "</div>");
        var div = document.getElementById("boxf");
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
        //document.getElementById('xyz').play();
    });
    socket.on('disuser', function(data){
        $("#boxf").append('<div class="alert alert-info">Server: ' +data+" has left the chat" + "</div>");
        var div = document.getElementById("boxf");
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
    });

    $('#pm').click(function(e){
        var whisp = $('#whisp').val();
        var recipent = $('#recipent').val();
        console.log(recipent);
        socket.emit('whisper', {whisp: whisp, user: recipent});
        $('#whisp').val('');
        $('#recipent').val('');
        return false;
    });
    $('#whiisper').on('click', '.MyButton', function(){
        var user1 = $(this).val();
        $('#recipent').val(user1);
    });
    console.log('hey');
    socket.on('whisper', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.user === username){
            $('#messes').append('<div class="alert alert-info" >' + data.user + ': ' + data.whisp + "</div>");
        }else{
            console.log('ahaaaaahhh');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

That is my script and here is how I have included JQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
```

Comment: Try with `$('#MyButton').on('click', function(){..}`

Comment: Works here: [http://jsfiddle.net/a6e979b4/](http://jsfiddle.net/a6e979b4/). Probably you don't have `jQuery` included in your page?

Comment: Where is your JS code placed? Be sure it's inside of document.ready

Comment: That is not working... just tried :(

Comment: It IS inside document.ready. And I also have JQuery. all my other functions work

Comment: @SaiAshwin you need to be more specific as to _what's not working_ as in the fiddle, when you click on  the button the value `Go!` gets set to the input!

Comment: try var user1 = $('#MyButton').val();

Comment: Okay and @LShetty Nothing ever gets entered into the textfield

Comment: Could It be because the button is actually in a list of users (My websites a chat server with node.js ) and buttons are added as and when a user connects?

Comment: The problem can't be repeated with the code that you posted, you have to look for an error where you use the code. Check for errors in the console. Debug the code or put an `alert`/`console.log` next to and inside the code to see if it runs at all.

Comment: If you add the elements after the code runs, that would mean that the event is not bound because the elements doesn't exist when the code runs.

Comment: @Guffa  the .on('click' does not even execute as nothing logs to the console when I remove the console.log outside this function and put it inside the function

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), such as `$(document).on("click", "#MyButton", function() { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: @LShetty That does not work :(

Comment: You have the Socket.io linked too?

Comment: Is the HTML you posted exactly as you have it? I can get your code working with your HTML and jQuery

Comment: Yes That is all of my html.. I shall post my whole html code (it is actually ejs if that helps.)

Comment: By the way, you have `'#whiisper'` instead of `'#whisper'` if that is important

Comment: Actually I fixed that in my code only after my post. It still doesnt work @Drakes

Comment: @Drakes, Stackoverflow goes haywire when I try to post my code Just because of indentation.. It displays a part of my code instead of showing it as a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle events for dynamically added elements, you can use event delegation. You would need to bind the event to a containing element that exists from start.

If you have multiple elements, then the id doesn't work to identify them as it has to be unique, you would use a class instead.

To find the input element you would need to traverse the DOM to find the one next to the button.

Example:

```
$('#ButtonContainer').on('click', '.MyButton', function(){
    var user1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).prev().val(user1);
});
```

Make sure that the buttons has a class that you can use to recognise them. Example:

```
<div id="ButtonContainer">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to">
  <button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to">
  <button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to">
  <button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>
</div>
```

Demo, using dynamically added elements:

```js
$('#ButtonContainer').on('click', '.MyButton', function(){
    var user1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).prev().val(user1);
});

$('#ButtonContainer').append('<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to"><button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>');
$('#ButtonContainer').append('<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to"><button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>');
$('#ButtonContainer').append('<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to"><button class="MyButton btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>');
```

```html
<div id="ButtonContainer">
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Strange... It doesn't work on my machine..... But if i paste the exact code you have done... It works!!

Comment: @SaiAshwin: Verify that the code snippet works on your machine. Check for differences in the code, for example the use of classes.

Comment: Do the classes, the aria label and type, placeholder have to be in some sort of order? that is the only way my code is different

Comment: @SaiAshwin: No, the attribute order doesn't matter. Check that you don't have double class attributes, that one almost got me.

Comment: No double class attributes @Guffa

Comment: @SaiAshwin: If you can't see any differences, then you are back to debugging the code. Check the error log, check if the code actually runs. You can use for example `console.log($('#ButtonContainer').length);` to check that jQuery finds an element.

Comment: the console says 0 @Guffa

Comment: @SaiAshwin: That means that jQuery didn't find the element. Check that it exists.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is working with this scaffolding. When the "GO" button is clicked, "Go!" appears in the text input. Please make sure jQuery is included, and the MyButton button isn't dynamically created *after* the page loads.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#MyButton').click(function(){
        var user1 = $(this).attr("value");
        $('#MyTextField').val(user1);
    });
}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MyTextField" aria-label="..." placeholder="User to send to">
  <button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-success" value="Go!">GO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I checked everything... It still doesn't work! So srange

Comment: Could you try this code in an html file on your side to verify that it does what you would like? Then we can explore more trouble spots

Comment: strangely, that Works!

Comment: When and where do you execute the `$('#MyButton').click(function() ...` code? Could you post that section please?

Comment: Can you please head over to this fiddle and verify that the Go button is doing what you expect it to do? http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/2345j2d9/

Comment: Yes it is doing precisely what I wanted... but only My code does i with usernames instead of GO

Comment: @SaiAshwin Has this answer aided you with your issue?

Comment: actually it was a dynamically created button.... i fixed the issue but facing another related to my host anyway thanks for your effort in answering the question